Where does the word "treat" belong to in this context?

All over the social layout this tightening-up and squeezing together
is an inconvenience, but when it comes to the areas of sovereign
states it becomes impossibly dangerous. It becomes an intolerable
thing; human life cannot go on, with the capitals of most of the
civilised countries of the world within an hour's bombing range of
their frontiers, behind which attacks can be prepared and secret
preparations made without any form of control. And yet we are still
tolerant and loyal to arrangements that seek to maintain this state of
affairs and treat it as though nothing else were possible.
The New World Order by H.G.Wells p. 33
(Bolds by me)

Where does the word "treat" belong to in this context? Which word is the subject of the verb "treat"? I have two variants.

Arrangements that treat.

In this case I am not sure figuratively if an "arrangement" can is something that the verb "treat" can be attributed to? I mean can an "arrangement" treat anything?

we (implied) treat.

Which version is the correct one?

It's unclear unless further context helps clarify. Another version of #1 would be "Arrangements that seek to ... treat." Given all the possibilities, 2 seems the most likely. This would be supported if broader context talks about how individuals should perceive the situation or should act in response.

... we are still tolerant and loyal to arrangements that seek to maintain this state of affairs, and treat it [this state of affairs] as though nothing else were possible It is very clear, and no other interpretation makes sense. Wells was a good writer.

It's an artificial ambiguity - imho the sense of the entire containing utterance is exactly the same regardless of how you parse it for the implied subject of treat. Syntactically, both parsings are possible, obviously. If it matters to you, choose the one that makes most sense to you.

to maintain this state of affairs and treat it. For arrangements, it has to be: to maintain this state of affairs and treat them.  There is no ambiguity. I believe Michael Harvey agrees.

@Lambie I'm not sure anyone, OP included, has suggested "we are loyal to arrangements and [compound verb:] we treat arrangements." I see several other possibilities, though as FumbleFingers says, they all drive at the same point.

He was HG Wells, not 'HH Wells'.

I've edited the question. I am asking about which word is the subject of the verm "treat"? As in "who treats"?

Quote: And yet we are still tolerant and loyal to arrangements that seek to maintain this state of affairs and treat it as though nothing else were possible.
treat it refers to this state of affairs. Not arrangements.

I disagree. At the syntactic level, both parsings are possible, and you can't defend the "implied subject must be state of affairs" position on the grounds that (inanimate / abstract) arrangements can't treat something as something, since we've just read that those same arrangements unambiguously seek to do something. You're just choosing the parsing that makes most sense to you.

@FumbleFingers Then, it would have to be them for arrangements. This way:  treat them as though nothing else were possible.

@Lambie - absolutely.

I'm not sure I follow FumbleFingers' comment here, but I don't think the OP is under the impression that the antecedent of "it" is "affairs." They are asking whether the subject of "treat" is "we" or "arrangements."

I think I got mixed up because this answer assumes this state of affairs and arrangements are the two possible implied but unstated subjects for the verb treat it as though nothing else were possible. But clearly this state of affairs is it (the object, not subject). Syntactically, the two possible subjects are we and arrangements. And like I said, those arrangements are explicitly seeking to do something, so the issue of "conscious agent, volitional act" is no barrier to the latter interpretation. Overall meaning is unchanged either way, imho.

If Wells, and the editors his publishers could afford by 1940, let that get into print, they must have thought it was OK.

Disregard the downvote.
